# Empty result set being returned. Don't understand why

Tags: mysql

This is the table.
[image]

And the query executed in phpmyadmin is

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE  hashed_password = '8c1017982b2032cc059203e3d83dd0ee2e7a86b3'`

And the result is an empty result set. If the query is 
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='tt'`
Then it works as expected.

Why ? is there something obvious that I am missing?
the password was hashed using php's sha1()

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE hashed_password LIKE '8c1017982b2032cc059203e3d83dd0ee2e7a86b3%'` give empty result set.

Output of "show create table users"

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hashed_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `favourites` text,
  `ip_address` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `trust_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Output of `select hashed_password, length(hashed_password) from users`
[image]

Comment: can you try this: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE hashed_password LIKE '%8c1017982b2032cc059203e3d83dd0ee2e7a86b3%'`

Comment: Could you show the `show create table users` statements output?

Comment: Yes  using LIKE returns the row just fine.

Comment: LIKE '%%' is bad try to use % from on side not both

Comment: I didn't mean use it - I just meant to test whether there's something we're not seeing. What are the exact contents of that field?

Comment: which field ? the hashed_password one ? It's 8c1017982b2032cc059203e3d83dd0ee2e7a86b3

Comment: I have tested your query it is working ok there is no problem. I have tested it on phpMyAdmin and SQL yog no problem at all.

Comment: Is it possible it's had a (or some) spaces added the end?  Having learned something from Leonard Challis' suggestion, now try this: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE hashed_password LIKE '8c1017982b2032cc059203e3d83dd0ee2e7a86b3%'` - if that works you *could* feasibly use it (but I would prefer not to).   It would also be interesting to do `select hashed_password, length(hashed_password) from users` and see if there's variation there.

Answer (score 1):

Your hashes are 40 chars long (SHA-1 looks like) while your database fields contain 42 characters. Obviously, any 42-char hash will not compare equal to the 40-char literal you provide. Moreover, it seems that the two extra characters are at the beginning of the hash (otherwise the `LIKE` trick should have worked).

Find out why there are two more characters in there -- the code that inserts the hashes might know something about that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(hashed_password) = '8c1017982b2032cc059203e3d83dd0ee2e7a86b3'
```